# Dynamic username in svn:externals URL

Tags: svn, svn-externals

In my project directory I have svn:externals set to the following:

```
library svn+ssh://MY_USERNAME@some.server.com/library
```

where `MY_USERNAME` is my personal username. It works for me, but if another person checks out my project it will fail since they can't log in with my username. Is it possible to somehow make `MY_USERNAME` become the username of whoever checked out the project or the username used when running svn update on the library folder?

Comment: Wouldn't it default to the current user if you omit it altogether?

Comment: When omitting the username I'm prompted to enter a username when I update using TortoiseSVN. I haven't been able to try it on the command line since I keep getting "svn: Can't create tunnel: The parameter is incorrect."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to create another user with read only access?

Another option that you can try is to try [Keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.keywords) but I have no idea if it will work on properties.

Have you tried [relative urls](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals)?

- ../ Relative to the URL of the
  directory on which the svn:externals
  property is set
- ^/ Relative to the root of the
  repository in which the svn:externals
  property is versioned
- // Relative to the scheme of the URL
  of the directory on which the
  svn:externals property is set
- / Relative to the root URL of the
  server on which the svn:externals
  property is versioned

Comment: Relative URLs solved my problem. The externals I have specified were luckily all located in the same repository. For anyone reading this, relative URLs are only available in repositories of version 1.5 and up.